# Moving diagrams between projects in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a project with several diagrams (with elements). I want to close this particular project and move the diagrams to other more suitable projects.

Moving a diagram is simple. Problem is that now I have to manually find all related element to this particular diagram and move them one by one to the other project. As I have quite a few elements in all diagrams in the original project this is quite tedious.

I wonder if there's an easier way of handling refactoring like this in EA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easier way in out-of-the-box EA, no. But where there's a will there's a way.

First off, make a copy of your project. The solution I'm describing will destroy its structure.

Second, create an empty package and move the diagram there.

Third, create a VBScript in the `Browserscript` group (Tools - Scripting). Call it "Collect Diagram Elements". In the editor, replace the commented-out `otDiagram` case with the following:

```
case otDiagram
    ' Code for when a diagram is selected
    dim theDiagram as EA.Diagram
    set theDiagram = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject()
    dim dObj as EA.DiagramObject
    dim element as EA.Element
    for each dObj in theDiagram.DiagramObjects
        set element = Repository.GetElementByID(dObj.ElementID)
        element.PackageID = theDiagram.PackageID
        element.Update()
    next
```

This script runs through all the elements shown in a diagram and moves them to the package the diagram is in.

Run the script by right-clicking the diagram in the package browser and selecting Scripts - Collect Diagram Elements. After the script finishes, you may need to reload the package (right-click the package in the package browser, select Contents - Reload Current Package).

Finally, export the package to XMI (right-click in the package browser, select Import/Export - Export Package to XMI File), and then import it into your target project.

Comment: The conclusion is, it is a good practise to put diagrams with their elements to separate packages. This will allow to export and import them easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to put you diagramme inside a package and then export it to XML file and import it from the destination project.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

**FOR EA VERSION 15**

**Project 1** - *from where you want to copy a diagram*

1. Do a Ctrl+A (select all) on your diagram.
2. Publish -> Save -> Save to Clipboard.

**Project 2** - *where the diagram will be pasted*

1. Create an empty diagram.
2. Right-Click (on the empty diagram) -> Paste -> Image from Clipboard

**FOR EA VERSION 10**

**Project 1** - *from where you want to copy a diagram*

1. Do a Ctrl+A (select all) on your diagram.
2. Edit -> Project Clipboard -> Add to Project Clipboard.

**Project 2** - *where the diagram will be pasted*

1. Create an empty diagram.
2. Edit -> Paste Image from Clipboard.

This will copy the diagram as a whole image (single component) and I think you will not be able to change the actual components of the diagram once it is pasted in the new project.

Comment: Are there still people using EA version 10 today? Dat version was released almost a decade ago.

Comment: Yep. Some organizations are still using it. And that's why I specifically mentioned this as first thing. Also, the same functionality is present in EA 15 version. Anyway I will add that also to my solution.

Comment: this only copies the image of a diagram, not the actual diagram or the elements on it. This is like pasting a printscreen of a document into Word.

Answer (score -2):

1. Right Click on Diagram you want to duplicate in other project
2. Copy / Paste
3. Copy to Clipboard
4. Full Structure for Duplication

you can paste it when you navigate to the right folder or Model in the other project.

Comment: There is no option "Copy to clipboard" or "Full structure for Duplication" in the context menu of a diagram.